# Connection Error Running Spring Application With Maven

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am trying to run a simple Spring application through Maven.

I have followed the following guide exactly: https://spring.io/guides/gs/serving-web-content/

However, when I run:   `./mvnw spring-boot:run -e -X`
I get the following error:

> [FATAL] Non-resolvable parent POM for org.springframework:gs-serving-web-content:0.1.0: Could not transfer artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:1.5.2.RELEASE from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Connect to 192.168.208.51:3128

In a previous guide I was told to add this as the settings.xml file in the .m2 directory:

```
<settings>
  <proxies>
    <proxy>
        <id>example-proxy</id>
        <active>true</active>
        <protocol>http</protocol>
        <host>192.168.208.51</host>
        <port>3128</port>
        <nonProxyHosts>*.google.com|*example.com</nonProxyHosts>
    </proxy>
  </proxies>
</settings>
```

Which has the host IP address that the error is referring to.

I've pinged the IP address above and no response.

All I want to do is run the application locally as the Spring.io guide suggests is possible.

I don't fully understand the setup as of yet.

Can anyone suggest what I'm doing wrong. (I feel it is something to do with the IP address in the settings.xml file.

Answer (score 0):

The IP you're using is in the private [network range](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network).

Comment: Okay, have you any suggestions on what this should be changed to?

Comment: Not really, why do you want a proxy? Add a link to the example from which it came?

Comment: Ahh! I didn't realise I didn't need the proxy setting in the settings file. Problem solved. Thanks.